# Directive / *ngIf only called one time, enable to redraw new direction on map

Tags: angular, google-maps, angular-directive

first of all, this is my first time working with angular, I took this mini project to familiarize myself with this framework.

in this project, I have a start and destination coordinates, and waypoints coordinates. and I want google maps to give direction from start to end point using waypoints.

I am using Angular Google Maps: https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps , since it does not support maps direction I created a directive which will draw the direction on the map
Here is some code in plnkr : https://plnkr.co/edit/JtZrBJHNufUFWnVjwcxX

```
  <agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng">
<!--<agm-marker-->
<!--*ngFor="let m of markers; let i=index"-->
<!--[latitude]="m.lat"-->
<!--[longitude]="m.lng"-->
<!--&gt;</agm-marker>-->

<appAgmMapDirections
  *ngIf="drawRoute == true"
  [origin]="origin"
  [destination]="destination"
  [waypoints]="wayPoints"
  [directionsDisplay]="directionsDisplay"
></appAgmMapDirections>
```

the problem I have is that the direction will only be drawn one time, it won't remove the old direction and draw the new one. It was working before but not anymore

I noticed the directive only called one time

> *ngIf="drawRoute"

even when the drawRoute value has changed.

what could be the problem here? 
thank you in advance.

Comment: What exactly is drawRoute? Share some more code.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz Sorry i forgot to add the plnkr link , thanks for reminding me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the `drawRoute` to `false` and `true` within the same change detection cycle. A workaround would be to set it to false, then use a `setTimeout` to force another change detection cycle to run:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.drawRoute = true;
}, 100);
```